# Why does EF Core fill a NULL Navigation Property with a Circular Self-Reference?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have an Entity Frameworks setup with a Server class. The server has a foreign key column that points at another Server entry like this.

```sql
CREATE TABLE (Server
    ServerRef bigint NOT NULL,
    ...
    ServerReplacementRef bigint NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ServerRef),
    FOREIGN KEY (ServerReplacementRef) REFERENCES Server(ServerRef)
);
```

I have setup the entity using the fluent design like this.

```csharp
modelBuilder.Entity<Server>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => e.ServerRef);
    entity.ToTable("tbl_Server");

    ...
    ...
    entity.HasProperty(e => e.ReplacementForServerRef)
        .HasColumnName(Server_Replacement_For_Server_Ref)

    entity.HasOne(d => d.ReplacementForServer)
        .WithMany(p => p.InverseServer_Replacement_For_ServerRef)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.ServerRef)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_tbl_Server_Server_Ref_Replacement_Ref")
});
```

Now, I'm pulling a Server from the database using the DbSet.Find() method with a NULL value in its ServerReplacementRef field and with no servers that reference it in theirs. Since the Replacement Server reference is NULL, I would expect both the Replacement inverse navigation collection and the Replacement navigation property to be NULL.

However, that's not what happens. Instead, both properties contain a reference to itself and if either of those references are missing when updating the entity, it will delete the entity from the database as if it had been orphaned instead of updating it. I was wondering if anyone else had had a similar experience and knew the reason why EF Core fills those navigation properties.

Edit:
It's worth noting that the Ref properties in the entities are NULL. It's only the navigation properties that are being filled with the circular self-reference. Also, as long as those self-references are there, it updates the database without error and without adding those self-references to the database itself.

Comment: This can happen sometimes based on the type of loading being used. Lazy loading will continue to load navigation properties while the context remains open, for example. What I am getting at though, is that this will also depend on the use and configuration of the current connection, not just based on the definition in the model.

Comment: Interesting, I've tried to find information about it online but I haven't found anything. I spent four or five hours today trying to figure out why my application was deleting the entries from the database instead of updating them. If you know what settings are relevant and can point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate you telling me.

Comment: I manually compose my EF classes and manually update object graphs, so I am not intimately familiar with the automated approach being used, especially not in EF Core. Some of the information on how it was designed prior to core is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ee373856(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/dd468057(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN . That may be a good place to look for keywords to move on with regards to finding related info in ef core.

Comment: `.HasForeignKey(d => d.ReplacementForServerRef)`? The change tracker will link navigations together if the objects are loaded. But you've defined a FK where both sides of the relationship are the PK column.

Comment: `.HasForeignKey(d => d.ServerRef)` feels wrong and probably is the culprit. Should be `.HasForeignKey(d => d.ReplacementForServerRef)`

Comment: That does fix the problem. All of that code was scaffolded from the database so there must be an issue in the scaffolding. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the commenters, I found that the Foreign Key definition was pointed at the Server ID instead of at the actual Replacement Server ID.

When I was pushing changes to the database, I had accidentally removed one of those circular references and EF Core assumed that my entity was orphaned. So, it was deleting it from the database instead of updating it.